# How do I copy data from CPU to GPU in a C++ process and run TF in another python process while pointing to the copied memory?

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow

I am working on an infrastructure that runs multiple C++ applications that work on certain "pre-processing" steps before running a DL step in a pool of Python TF based applications. I was wondering if there's an easy way for me to copy the required model and data to GPU memory from the C++ application and then just hand-off "GPU pointers" to the python application to pick up the data and run TF.
[image: "Precopy" data to GPU memory]

Basically, I would like to avoid the process of sending data from the C++ app to the python app thus avoiding unnecessary copy steps.
[image]

I could potentially use shared memory to hand the data off to the python process, but the concern is that shared memory management might be too cumbersome considering the number of C++ applications and python applications that I will end up running. There are performance concerns as well in using shared memory as it needs a good deal of synchronization.

Answer (score -1):

Simple answer - No. Because what you want is an memory attack and thus prohibited by Linux. If a program can read another program's stack then no secret can be safe in memory.

The alternative is to introduce a middleware such as Memchached or Redis to let both programs share this data in it.

Comment: Simple answers are not always right. While accessing the memory of another process is not possible by default, there are ways to allocate "CPU Memory" to be shared between processes, and for the GPU side, there are also ways to do that  (e.g. [`CUDA IPC`](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#interprocess-communication)).  Whether or not it is possible to solve the problem of the OP using these methods is hard to tell.